A General Analysis of Charge Distribution inside conductors
I'll go ahead and present my question straight-forward and then talk about the calculation details.My Question is: how do you define a conductor in Electrostatics? What are the basic(minimum) set of properties we need about a material To call it a conductor and derive all the other properties about the material from the basic Properties.
I know this is a lame question and any Electrostatics textbook covers this topic. But I had a lot of free time to spare So I tried the maths and got confused. Here's the Calculation.

The First Property of conductors I considered is that they have the same potential on each surface point. I will start my calculations by using Green's first identity.
$$\oint_{V}\left[\phi\nabla^2\psi+(\nabla\phi)\cdot(\nabla\psi)\right]d^3x=\oint_{S}\phi\frac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial{n}}da$$
Using Substitution $\phi\to\Phi$ and $\psi\to\Phi$ where $\Phi$ represents the potential inside the region. Using Poisson's equation, we get
$$-\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\oint_V\Phi(\textbf{x})\rho(\textbf{x})d^3x\,\,\,+ \oint_V|\nabla\Phi|^2d^3x = \Phi\oint_S\nabla\Phi\cdot\textbf{n}da$$
Above we used the fact that $\Phi$ is Constant on the surface and thus can be taken out of the Surface Integral.
The Surface integral is extremely familiar as the Flux due to the Electric Field
$$\oint_S{\nabla\Phi\cdot\textbf{n}da}=\frac{Q_{encl}}{\epsilon_0}$$
Where $Q_{encl}$ is the total charge on the Conductor(Volume+Surface).
$$-\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\oint_V\Phi(\textbf{x})\rho(\textbf{x})d^3x\,\,\,+ \oint_V|\nabla\Phi|^2d^3x = \frac{\Phi Q_{encl}}{\epsilon_0}$$
Multiplying both sides by $\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}$
$$-\frac{1}{2}\oint_V\Phi(\textbf{x})\rho(\textbf{x})d^3x\,\,\,+ \frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\oint_V|\nabla\Phi|^2d^3x = \frac{\Phi Q_{encl}}{2}$$
From Electrostatic Potential Energy we know
$$\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\int|\textbf{E}|^2d^3x = \frac{1}{2}\int \rho(\textbf{x})\Phi(\textbf{x})d^3x$$
$$\Phi(\textbf{x})\cdot Q_{encl}=0$$
And here I started having problems, Generally When some charge was given to a conductor, it spread on the surface of the conductor such that no charge was there inside the Conductor. I assume here that in general $\Phi(\textbf{x})\neq 0$. We get
$$Q_{encl}=0$$
Here we can also say
$$Q_{encl}=Q_{volume}+Q_{surface}$$
and
$$Q_{volume}=-Q_{surface}$$
and if the Total charge inside the volume is $0$, Then the surface charge is $0$, which is not general. I can give any amount to charge to the conductor and It will spread itself on the surface. What is going wrong here? Also, I put no constraints on the charge density. $Q_{volume}$ being $0$ doesn't mean there is no charge inside the conductor, I never said that. Now, The condition that it is a surface of the same potential is not enough. So what is the other condition? Remember that the minimum number of conditions is needed only.


A conductor is a body within which:

Charge moves freely
Charge cannot escape through the surface

A corollary of the first point is that the net force on any infinitesimal volume of charge must be zero when the system is in equilibrium. These infinitesimal charges obey the laws of electrostatics, so they will mutually repel regions of like polarity, and will mutually attract regions of opposite polarity. A conductor with a non-zero net charge can be considered as a volume of infinitesimal charged regions of the same polarity, which thus mutually repel.
Therefore, combining both parts of the definition above, within a conductor we must have the following:

All charge must be bound to the surface (or else interior charges would mutually repel until they reached the surface; we only consider the equilibrium case after this has settled)
The tangential electric force acting on each infinitesimal surface charge (due to every other surface charge) must be zero.

These conditions are necessary consequences of the basic definition given above. From them, you can apply Coulomb's law across the surface of the conductor, assuming no external charges; or apply Coulomb's law across the entire volume of space when external charges are present. This allows us to further derive properties like the equipotential surface.

Edit. Regarding your math, there's one small (and pretty much irrelevant) mistake in the signs of Gauss's law, and one harder to spot mistake in the energy equations. The issue comes when you equate these two forms of electric potential energy:
$$
\begin{align}
U_E &= \frac{1}{2}\int_V \rho \Phi\,dV\\
U_E' &= \frac{\epsilon}{2} \int_V |\nabla \Phi|^2\,dV \\
\end{align}
$$
These are not quite the same. The first equation is the electric potential energy of a volume with charge density $\rho$ and electric potential $\Phi$ defined throughout the volume. This is quite general, since it's essentially a statement of the work required to "bring the charge density into position." The second equation is obtained by integrating the electric energy density in a vacuum,
$$
u_E = \frac{1}{2} \epsilon_0 \mathbf{E}^2
$$
and integrating this over your volume does, indeed, give the problem you found. However, the derivation of that expression reveals a missing term in your case, a term associated with the electric field about the surface.
Let $V$ be an arbitrary medium with charge density $\rho$. The electric potential energy of the volume is
$$
U_E = \frac{1}{2} \int_V \rho \Phi\,dV.
$$
Using the differential form of Gauss's law, we can rewrite this
$$
\frac{\epsilon}{2}\int_V (\nabla\cdot \mathbf{E})\Phi\,dV.
$$
Use the following identity,
$$
(\nabla\cdot \mathbf{E})\Phi = -\mathbf{E}\cdot\nabla\Phi + \nabla\cdot (\mathbf{E}\Phi)
$$
to obtain
$$
U_E = \frac{\epsilon_0}{2} \int_V \nabla\cdot(\mathbf{E}\Phi)\,dV - \frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\int_V \mathbf{E}\cdot\nabla\Phi\,dV
$$
We can rearrange this using the divergence theorem and some combining:
$$
U_E = \frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\oint_{S} (\mathbf{E}\Phi)\cdot \hat{n}\,dA + \frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\int_V |\nabla \Phi|^2\,dV.
$$
Ordinarily at this point we would suppose the volume extends to infinity, and thus taking $\Phi \rightarrow 0$ at infinity, the surface integral vanishes. Then we can derive the energy density, and re-integrate to get the total energy in a volume. But instead, let's keep the volume $V$ and its bounding surface $S$ to the same ones in our application. Thus, supposing $\Phi$ is constant across the surface, we get
$$
U_E = \frac{\epsilon_0 \Phi}{2} \oint_S \mathbf{E}\cdot\hat{n}\,dA + \frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\int_V |\nabla \Phi|^2\,dV
$$
and by Gauss's law,
$$
U_E = \frac{1}{2}\Phi q_{encl} + \frac{\epsilon_0}{2} \int |\nabla \Phi|^2\,dV.
$$
Substituting this into the equations you derived, the two integrals are not equal, but instead there is an additional term. Specifically, from this equation:
$$
\frac{-1}{\epsilon} \int_V \rho\Phi\,dV + \frac{\epsilon}{2}\int_V |\nabla\Phi|^2\,dV = \frac{-\Phi q_{encl}}{2}
$$
substituting our energy equations, we actually get
$$
-U_E + (U_E - \frac{1}{2}\Phi q_{encl} ) = \frac{-1}{2} \Phi q_{encl}
$$
or
$$
\frac{-1}{2} \Phi q_{encl} = \frac{-1}{2} \Phi q_{encl}
$$
which is true, though unfortunately not very helpful as a condition.
Further Explanation. I was myself still a bit unsure of where the problems were coming in with simply using the energy density equation instead of rederiving it. To better understand, I looked a bit closer at energy density, remembering something about an extra surface term. The problem, I realized, is assuming that:
$$
U_E = \int_V u_E\,dV.
$$
This is not true. In fact, you can find (e.g. in Griffiths 2.4.3) that in fact
$$
U_E = \int_V u_E\,dV + \frac{\epsilon}{2}\oint_S \mathbf{E}\Phi\cdot\hat n\,dA
$$
(Griffiths eqn 2.44) which is the same as derived in my answer.
Clearly the leftover term is a boundary term, so we might naively interpret it as the energy contribution of any external charges. But there is actually a more natural interpretation: it represents all remaining energy from the $\mathbf E$ contributions outside of the specified volume. Griffiths section 2.4.4 covers this nicely. Mathematically, we are simply left with the fact that you cannot equate the two integral expressions as you did, even though it seems naively like it should work.

At first I was going to get into the math, but thought I'd answer your main question (in bold) first. No need to complicate the definition. But, if you're looking for an additional condition that, combined with the equipotential surface, gives necessary and sufficient conditions for a body to be considered a conductor, then I think starting from the equipotential surface is a bit questionable, since it's a weaker condition than requiring zero tangential electric field. I'll look through your math when I have a minute.

@Charu_Bamble updated the answer to explain your math issues, hope it helps!
